# How to make a similar equation environment like the picture?

Tags: equations, align

I think there are many ways to create a similar enviornment like the picture below, but I am unsure what is the easiest way to do this. My code is the following, but I know it isn't like this. I am going to need this environment like in the picture several times, so it would be nice to know how to create this.

```
  \text{Pr}\Bigg[
  \begin{eqnarray*}
    (pp, t) \leftarrow \textsf{Setup}(1^k, m) & & \\
    (pvk, x, aux) \leftarrow \textsf{Stretch}(pp), & : & 
    \textsf{Verify}(pp, pvk, t, i, x_i, \pi) = 1 \\
    \pi \leftarrow \textsf{Prove}(pp, aux, i) & & \\
  \end{eqnarray*}
  \Bigg]
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `\text` for that function name, it does not do what you think. Use `\operatorname{Pr}` or even better define it using `\DeclareMathOpeator{\Pr}{Pr}` in the preamble. Why is `\text` wrong? It switches to the current text font (function names should be in the upright math font) and as it follows the surrounding text, if that text is italics the output of `\text` is also italics.

Comment: Unrelated 2: don't use the eqnarray envrionment, it has a lot of shortcomings.

Comment: What is your aim ? Typeset the equation of the image, or create a macro that would help to build similar things ?

Comment: @daleif Ok, thanks for the information, gonna change those things!

Comment: @Jhor My aim is to typeset the equation of the image, but I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the below code meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\pp}{\operatorname{pp}}
\newcommand{\pvk}{\operatorname{pvk}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Pr
\begin{bmatrix*}[l]
    (\pp, \tau) \xleftarrow{\$}{}\text{Setup}(1^{\lambda}, m)  \\
    (\text{pvk}, x, \text{aux}) \xleftarrow{\$}{} \text{Stretch}(\pp), :     \text{Verify}(\pp, \pvk, \tau, i, x_i, \pi) = 1 \\
    \pi \xleftarrow{\$}{} \text{Prove}(\pp, \text{aux}, i)
\end{bmatrix*}=1.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use this, thank you, it works!

Comment: @Burak Glad to hear that my suggestion works for you...

Answer (score 4):

I propose a solution based on `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\PR}[1]{\operatorname{Pr}}{[} {]}{}{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}#1 \end{array}}

\begin{document}

    \[ \PR*{ (\mathsf{pp}, \mathcal{T}) \xleftarrow{\$} \textsf{Setup}(1^k, m) \\
 (\mathsf{pvk}, x, \mathsf{aux}) \xleftarrow{\$} \textsf{Stretch}(\mathsf{pp}), : \textsf{Verify}(\mathsf{pp}, \mathsf{pvk},\mathcal{T}, i, x_i, \pi) = 1 \\
 \pi \xleftarrow{\$} \textsf{Prove}(\mathsf{pp}, \mathsf{aux}, i)} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the [`empheq`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PR}{Pr}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left={\PR = \empheqlbrack},right={\empheqrbrack = 1}]{align*}
&   (pp, t) \leftarrow \textsf{Setup}(1^k, m)  \\
&   (pvk, x, aux) \leftarrow \textsf{Stretch}(pp), : \textsf{Verify}(pp, pvk, t, i, x_i, \pi) = 1 \\
&    \pi \leftarrow \textsf{Prove}(pp, aux, i) 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]